# OpenCV copyMakeBorder changes grayscale value

Tags: python, image, image-processing, opencv

I'm trying to add pad to my image which is a grayscale image using copyMakeBorder. It does work and adds the padding that I want but grayscale values change, image gets brighter. I want to keep my values and just add padding. Why does it even interact with colors?

```
padded_img = cv2.copyMakeBorder( img, 0, 0, 0, pad_value, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
```

[image]

Comment: How do you display the image? It looks like you are using a colormap with adaptive range. Due to the dark border the range of values changes which makes the visualization appear different.

Comment: [here](https://imgur.com/a/PELcU9v) is image in gray cmap. I'm using matplotlib's imshow function to display image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are displaying the image using a colormap with adaptive range. From the [documentation of matplotlib's imshow](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html):

> normNormalize, optional
> The Normalize instance used to scale scalar data to the [0, 1] range before mapping to colors using cmap. By default, a linear scaling mapping the lowest value to 0 and the highest to 1 is used. This parameter is ignored for RGB(A) data.

As your image only contains relatively light colors (high intensity values), it *appears* to you as if the image would lighten up with the border. In fact, the first display of your image without the border was darkened (contrast-enhanced) by imshow.

Pass a Normalize object to your imshow call to specify the correct value range of your image, e.g.

```
imshow(..., normNormalize=matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=255))
```

Do this for both before and after outputs.

Comment: thanks that did work, so I can assume this was only the case in imshow or should I normalize my image with cv like `img = cv2.normalize(img, img, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX)` ?

Comment: This issue is solely based on imshow's behavior. Your image data need no normalization. You could also use `cv2.imshow` which does not alter the intensities.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Reason I'm using matplotlib's imshow is because I'm working on google colab right now. I can't use cv's imshow on colab.

Answer (score 1):

ypnos answer is perfectly fine. Alternatively you can also make these changes to pyplot params and use imshow without worrying about having to add it every time you have to display it. For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (20, 20)
#  Grayscale mapping
plt.rcParams["image.cmap"] = 'gray'
# Now simply use imshow anywhere in your code
plt.imshow(img)
```

Comment: Using 'gray' cmap does not influence the normalization behavior of imshow.

Comment: Yes indeed! I misconstrued the problem :)